# $\sum_{a^2<p\leq (a+1)^2}p$ Summation of primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

$$\sum_{a^2<p\leq (a+1)^2}p$$ where p is prime. Are there some known bounds for this sum?

Comment: It is believed, but has not yet been proven, that there is always a prime between consecutive squares. Hence, for the lower bound, one cant even write any value greater than zero.

Comment: Would you be happy with an estimate? You could use the Prime Number Theorem to estimate the sum.